# Object Required VBA Strcomp function

Tags: vba, excel

We have an SQL database that exports to excel. Each record in the database is the evaluation of a project. Each project has a project identifier (string). Since a project can be evaluated two times, each project can have two records. The difference between the two records is the id number (number), with the most recent record having a higher id number. The records are exported to excel with each record as a row in the spread sheet. I am trying to write a sub that compares the two project identifiers and deletes the row with the lower id number. I keep getting an object required error for SameP.

```
Dim Pident1 As String
Dim Pident2 As String
Dim IdNumb1 As Variant
Dim IdNumb2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim SameP As Integer
i = 2

For i = 2 To 100

Pident1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Text
Pident2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Text
IdNumb1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
IdNumb2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
Set SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2, CompareMethod.Text)

If SameP = 0 And IdNumb1> Idnumb2 Then Data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not a programmer, i just try when I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Data name of any worksheet ? Because I don't think this `Data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` is right.

Comment: Thank you, No it isn't the name, to be honest i copied that line of code from a tutorial. I will update it to activeworksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2, CompareMethod.Text)
```

to this:

```
SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2)
```

The error is this line also

```
Data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Change this to

```
Sheets("Name_of_sheet_here").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Alternatively this would work too

```
Activeworksheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: That is the error he would get after solving the current one stated in the question

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've now done that, but the error still occurs. Id happens the first time I use SameP , in line 20.

Comment: Have you tried    SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2, CompareMethod.Text)      (get rid of the Set attribute)

Comment: @Dave Hamre , try SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2)

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I'm no longer getting the error. The code isn't doing what I'd like, but that's another quest :)

Comment: No problems Dave... check out [this page](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php) for further reading on the StrComp function. Not sure where the CompareMethod.Text came from?

Comment: If you want to edit the question to show the layout of the data, I'd be happy to help

Comment: Thanks Brendan, but it's confidential data, so I can't really post it. Thanks again though.

Comment: No problem... all the best with it!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Set SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2, CompareMethod.Text)

If SameP = 0 And IdNumb1> Idnumb2 Then Data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

to

```
SameP = StrComp(Pident1, Pident2, vbTextCompare )

If SameP = 0 And IdNumb1> Idnumb2 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately. Have i failed to define SameP in some way?

Comment: I tried the updated one and got the same error. Removing comparemethod.text stopped the error message. Now I just need to get the code to work.